# How to only allow swiping one slide at a time using swiperjs

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/) and would like to only allow the user to swipe one item at a time.

I am showing 1 slide per view `slidesPerView=1` as shown here: [parameters](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters).

I cannot see anything obvious to ensure the swiper only changes one slide at a time.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can not do that. At least, there's no straightforward way of doing it.
Swiper is a pretty limited and I'd say annoying library in its own way.

One way of implementing this is to set 'allowTouchMove' to false and then write  custom code of detecting a swipe, in order to call the swipe action manually using the slidePrev()/slideNext() methods.

You need to look at 'changedTouches' array in the touchend event and 'touches' array for the touchstart event. Comparing those two values will let you detect both the direction and the distance sufficient enough to consider it a swipe, rather than a click. Similar logic goes for mouse swipes.

I know this is 7 months old but other folks may come across.